# MIPS Assembly - reads an integer from a file

Tags: file, assembly, mips

Maybe someone knows the function that reads an integer from a file?

Thanks a lot.

```
li   $v0, 14       ## system call for ReadFile##
move $a0, $s0
la   $a1, buffer1        # O
li   $a2, 70
syscall
```

Comment: There is no syscall for that in MARS or SPIM.  You will have to parse the bytes in the file into what you want.

Comment: The following link, certainly answers your question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147952/reading-files-with-mips-assembly